# How do you lock the unit system?

Tags: units

Sorry completely new to Blender and currently trying to figure out how to change my unit system from metric to units.

I am able to get to the menus that enable me to choose what unit system I want to use but don't know why when I'm changing the major radium and minor radius of the donut it reconverts the unit system to metric.

Am I missing a step here?

Refer to 2:14 mark
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RaT-uG5wgUw

Comment: Undo adding the torus, then change the unit system, then add the torus again. It appears to be a bug.

Comment: Just for the record, a blender unit equals 1 meter, so even if you change from unspecified units to metric, nothing changes.

Comment: Thanks for the clarity - I also meant to say "from metric to feet" not units in my beginning statement

Comment: Units can be changed under the "Scene" tab in the Properties Panel.